# Unity3D - Relative position on y-axis independent of rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, trigonometry

I have an object (A) with another object (B) next to it. I am trying to calculate the "height" of object B, so that i can position another object at that height relative to the position of object A. I know this sounds like gibberish (i'm a bit tired) so i have put diagrams to try and explain.

So in the left image the yellow line represents what i am trying to calculate. I have an position (orange) on the surface of a cylinder (grey) (calculated position using mesh data) which i am trying to use to calculate the radius of the object (black line). To do this i need a position at the center of the object (grey) at the same height (red dot) so i can calculate the direction from one to the other and use the length (.magnitude) as the radius.

**My problem is i can't work out, how i can calculate the height (yellow line) without rotation having any effect.**

I currently use projectOnPlane however if i rotate the object as seen in the second image, the radius decreases significantly when it should be consistent as the object is not changing size.

```
Vector3 RadDirection = (Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orangePoint, grey.transform.up) - Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(grey.transform.position, grey.transform.up));
float radius = RadDirection.magnitude;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

**UPDATE: The grey block in the diagram is a vector3 position rather than a game object. The radius calculation i am trying to do happens during runtime so i can't parent an object to the grey and review the inspector.

**UPDATE 2: Sorry, something i should have mentioned. The object i'm doing this on will not always be a perfect cylinder, it could be something such as a wine glass, where i need to calculate the radius of the glass not the stem. Another example could be a chemistry beaker which normally tapers to a point, so i would need to calculate the radius at the height of the orange point. Sorry i should have put that in the question.

Here's a diagram to illustrate what i mean in update 2. Again the orange dot is acting as a visual representation of a Vector3 position on the surface of the object's (in this case a beaker) mesh.

**Update 3: I appear to have solved the issue and so i have posted my answer below but at the time of writing i can't accept it (have to wait 2 days) and so cant close/answer the question. I would like to thank everyone that contributed and tried to help me solve this problem. I hope i can help you all someday :)

[image]

Comment: the diagram is nice but we cant see whats wrong without code. although it sounds to me, if your just getting a measurement of a straight line, the radii you should use a ray from the center out. i assume were talking 3d? not 2d?

Comment: @Vanethrane I have added the code i'm current using that is affected by rotation

Comment: is `b` a child of `a`?

Comment: @Vanethrane no B is just a vector3 position on the surface of object A's mesh. I calculated it using the vertex data and a KdTree.

Comment: transform.localscale.z/2 will give you your radius more efficiently... gimme a second im throwing something together quick

Comment: @Vanethrane Thanks. The object i'm doing this one will not always be a perfect cylinder, it could be something such as a wine glass, where i need to calculate the radius of the glass not the stem. Another example could be a chemistry beaker which normally tapers to a point, so i would need to calculate the radius at the height of the orange point. Sorry i should have put that in the question.

Comment: ok got it, now we have enough info. im going to have a cig then give me five minutes, i have an idea with rays that should get what you need

Comment: colliders on these objects or no?

Comment: @Vanethrane trigger based box colliders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have solved my problem using the following:

```
public static Vector3 ProjectPointOnLine(Vector3 linePoint, Vector3 lineVec, Vector3 point)
    {
        //get vector from point on line to point in space
        Vector3 linePointToPoint = point - linePoint;

        float t = Vector3.Dot(linePointToPoint, lineVec);

        return linePoint + lineVec * t;
    }
```

I found this here, it has lot's of other useful looking functions:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions

I basically pass in the origin of the beaker (green point) as the "linePoint", the upwards direction of the beaker "lineVec" with beaker.transform.up and finally i pass in the world vector3 point on the surface of the beaker mesh (orange point) it returns back a point in the middle of the beaker at the same height as my orange dot. I then just subtract the one from the other and take the magnitude as the radius. The radius value calculated is correct in that's it the value i was expecting and only changes after the sixth decimal place during rotation which gives plenty of accuracy as i only need three or four decimal places.

I'm happy to provide further details or help if anyone else needs help doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform.TransformDirection()` or `transform.InverseTransformDirection()`

To get the height take the result of the subtraction and set the X, Z coordinate to zero:

```
Vector3 height = orangeBox.position - greenPoint.position; 
height.x = 0; 
height.z = 0;
```

Complete solution:

```
    Vector3 direction = orangeBox.position - greenPoint.position;
    direction = greyBox.transform.InverseTransformDirection(direction);
    direction.x = 0;
    direction.z = 0;
    height = direction.magnitude;
    redPoint.position = greenPoint.position + greyBox.transform.up * height;
```

Comment: if he changes the transform direction its going to change his method and the direction of transform.up

Comment: He can use the transform.TransformDirection() to calculate direction without changing the gameObject transform.

Comment: In order to do what you have put in your code snippet i need the height. The height is what i am trying to calculate

Comment: To get the height take the result of the subtraction and set the X, Z coordinate to zero: Vector3 heading = orangePoint.position - greenPoint.position;
heading.x = 0;
heading.z = 0;
height = heading.magnitude

Comment: That doesn't work the position changes when i rotate.

Comment: Please check my complete solution if yours won't work. I have tested it and it seems to work OK.